# How to combine several lists and put them as a single key into a dictionary?

Tags: python, search-engine

I'm creating a mini search engine in python language. For that I need to resolve the following problem. I have basically a text which is made of several parts separated by `"[==========]"`.

Like :

```
[blablabla][blabliblou][==========][blablablou][blibloubla][=========][oubabababa][baboulila]
```

I want to create an algorithm that combine these lists until we "hit" a "=========="and put them into a dictionary as a single key with the value "1" for the first lists, value "2" for the two following lists etc...

To be honest, I tried a lot of things but I couldn't resolve the problem.
Could you help me ?

I tried to create conditionals loops using for and while

```
file = open("mytext.txt","r", encoding="utf-8")

dico = {}
counter = 0

for ln in file:
    x = ln.split()
    for x in file:
        print(dico)
        while x != "==========":
           dico[x] = counter
        else:
            dico[x] = counter + 1

print (dico)
```

The dictionary is still empty, I don't know why!

Comment: Just a hint, consider this line: `for x in file:`

Comment: Thanks for your reply ! What's the point ? x is splited ln

Comment: could you show expected output?

Comment: This is my expected output : dico{blablabla blabliblou : 1, blablablou blibloubla : 2, oubabababa baboulila : 3}

Answer (score 0):

You could try using regular expressions.

```
import re
file = open("myfile.txt","r",encoding="utf-8")
dico = {}
data=file.read()
# split up string int a list of "stuff separated by one or more ="
keys = re.split(r"=+", data)
for i in range(len(keys)):
    dico[keys[i]] = i+1
```

keys:

```
    ['[blablabla][blabliblou]', '[blablablou][blibloubla]', '[oubabababa][baboulila]']
```

dico:

```
{'[blablabla][blabliblou]': 1, '[blablablou][blibloubla]': 2, '[oubabababa][baboulila]': 3}
```

edit: fixed a couple syntax errors.

Comment: Thanks a lot Matthew, I will try and let you know

Comment: I actually made a little mistake in the topic description, I forgot to precise that the "==========" are lists.